# mysql inserting records twice in database

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, cross-browser, propel

I have the simple code shown below. After it has run once, it inserts the results into MySQL database twice.
It is working fine in all browsers (IE, Chrome, and Safari) except Firefox.

I am using symfony php framework and propel as the ORM.

```
$con = Propel::getConnection();
   $sql =  "select * from tmp where user_id =$userid";  
   $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);  
   $stmt->execute(); 
   while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
   {
    $insert_sql = "INSERT IGNORE into library(xxx,xxx) VALUES('xyz','xys')";
    $insert_stmt = $con->prepare($insert_sql) ;
    $insert_stmt->execute();
   }
```

Comment: This code is running in your browser?!

Comment: Yes. records are inserted fine for all browsers except Firefox

Comment: There's no possible way this is running in your browser.  Php is server-side.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that the code you've posted is not the problem.  The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: actually, i am using symfony framework and the propel as the ORM

Comment: Just a note. You are using your symfony php framework and propel as the ORM in completely wrong way.

Comment: Sometimes, when you debug and refresh webpage after POST request (e.g. form submission) it sends data again. Maybe this is the trouble?

Answer (score 1):

Most of time it's being a consequence of unwise mod_rewrite usage, making some file act as a 404 error handler.
Thus, if some resource not found, such a file being called and executed.

Check HTTP headers when calling your page and see what additional requests being made.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is deeper.I am not a php developer, but I can understand the problem is the design. Ideally I think your client is making multiple request to your server and each request is inserting a record in the system before checking if the record already exists.

Comment: One way of checking idempotence is to check if the value is available before import. (Also have an abstraction layer between your UI and Service. Do not initiate the service call directly from your browser. )

Comment: Regardless of any relevance to this question, POST is generally the method thats *not* guaranteed/supposed to be idempotent.